# music file search in computer in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, search

I am trying to search  music file in my computer.I tried the code give below ,but it is giving results on when the name of the file is exactly same.

```
import fnmatch
import os
import webbrowser
song = raw_input("enter the song")
to_search = [song + '.mp3']

path = ['G:\\','F:\\','E:\\']
for k in path:
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(k):
       for extensions in to_search:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extensions):
            matches=(os.path.join(root, filename))
print matches
if not matches:
    print ("no such song is found")
else:
    webbrowser.open(matches)                       #play the song if found
```

Now I am trying to search the song also for the wrong spelling mistakes as the google also give the results if the spelling is wrong.Like if we type Michal jackson instead of Michael jackson it gives the result.So for this i tried the following code.

```
import os
import webbrowser
import difflib

song = raw_input("enter the song")
to_search = [song + '.mp3']
path = ['E:\\']
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path[0]):
    d = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,filenames, to_search).ratio()
    if d>=0.6:
        print d
        matches=(os.path.join(root,filenames))

webbrowser.open(matches)
```

but i am not getting the results.Can anyone tell me what is the mistake or why I am not getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try `glob` package and something like:

```
for file in glob.glob('G:\\*\\*.mp3"):
    print(file)
```

This might not probably be your entire answer but I guess you can get there from here.

Answer (score 0):

In `SequenceMatcher` you are comparing a list of several filenames with a list containing just the one you are looking for. Hence the non-match result.
Try the following:

```
import os
import webbrowser
import difflib


song = raw_input("enter the song")
to_search = song + '.mp3'
path = ['E:\\']
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path[0]):
    for filename in filenames:
        d = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None,filename, to_search).ratio()
        if d>=0.6:
            matches=(os.path.join(root, filename))

webbrowser.open(matches)
```

Comment: Pleasure chinesh, if this answer solves your problem please consider upvoting/accepting it.

Comment: I cant do so because i don have sufficient reputation to do so.Please upvote my question so that i can help you out :)

Comment: hey jacques...I want to make youtube API using Django rest-framework.Is it possible to do so.If yes,how should I start with.It would be mine first API i would be working upon.

Comment: You should ask another question and be more specific about what you want to achieve. I am probably not the best person to answer as I don't know much about google youtube API. Good luck !

Comment: okkk...can you tell what  good python coder should have knowledge about.